# jquery tooltip with while loop

Tags: php, jquery, loops, while-loop, tooltip

tooltip dont work with while loop
all the icons show me the info of first icon only
here is the php

```
$check = odbc_exec($conn,"select * from Item");
while($r = odbc_fetch_array($check)){
$info = $r['Info'];
$Image = $r['image'];
echo  "<span class='hint'><img src='$Image'></span>
<div class='readitem' style='display:none'>$info</div>";

}
```

jquery : tooltip

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changeTooltipPosition = function(event) {
      var tooltipX = event.pageX - 10;
      var tooltipY = event.pageY + 10;
      $('div.tooltip').css({top: tooltipY, left: tooltipX});};
    var showTooltip = function(event) {
    var item = $('.readitem').html();

      $('<div class="tooltip"><center>'+ item + '</center></div>').appendTo('body');
      changeTooltipPosition(event);
    };
    var hideTooltip = function() {
       $('div.tooltip').remove();
    };
    $(".hint").bind({
       mousemove : changeTooltipPosition,
       mouseenter : showTooltip,
       mouseleave: hideTooltip
    });
});

</script>
```

any solution ?

Thank You ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with the `var item = $('.readitem').html();` line.

When you do `$('.readitem')`, it will match all elements on the page which have that class. When then calling `.html()` on that, it'll return the html of the first matched element (thus always showing you the first one).

What you'd instead need to do, is look within the `.hint` on which you're hovering, in order to find the sibling `.readitem`, and then use the html of that one.

So, this should work instead:

```
var item = $(this).siblings('.readitem').html();
```

`$(this)` should be the instance of the `.hint` on which you are hovering, so you're trying to find the `.readitem` in the sibling elements of it.

Comment: Can you include in your original post the whole while loop?

Comment: i have added the orginal while loop i using

Comment: Hey DragoN, I've edited my answer now that I've understood the problem! I think that should fix it for you!

Comment: thx , but with find it give me Null error, so i used $(this).siblings

Comment: Ah, you're right, I misread the html. I thought the .readitem was within .hint, but they are at the same level. I'll update my answer to have the correct code!

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a while loop without a condition.
Your while loop should be formed like

```
while (condition) {
    //your code
}
```

where condition is an expression evaluated as true or false.
However in your case, you may have an array of icon URL. You should use a for loop which is more convenient to loop in an array.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
    echo $images[$i]; // Assuming $images is an array.  
}
```

Comment: i have added the orginal while loop i using